# Can epiphyte share nutrient to host plant?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

Sometimes plant share their nutrient with underground root network

But if there are plant that grow on other tree. Is it possible that it would merge into another tree and sharing resource. I mean opposite to parasite that it not steal resource but give the leftover to the host? Any plant do that?

I heard some plant like Coast Redwood or Banyan could grow their child on their branch as epiphyte. Can them sharing resource between each other?

Comment: No, per definition there is no connection between the epiphyte's and the host's vascular system. If there was, it would make the species a parasite.

Comment: Then are there any parasite specie that will give nutrient to host?

Comment: I doubt that and it wouldn't make much sense from an evolutionary perspective. What mechanism can you think of that would make it advantageous to waste your own nutrients to another, unrelated, plant species?

Comment: @Hav0k First, as I mention that some large tree could have their own specie grow on itself so if they could share nutrient it could benefit species as a whole. And second I think it could be like a relationship of market and landowner. When host get benefit to get stronger then the things rely on would be more secure

Comment: In the future, if you wish to change your question please edit it to do so rather than asking followup questions in the comments. Comments are impermanent and should not contain information essential to understanding the question. Thanks!